# CRUD program to read,write and append the details in txt file

Tags: python-3.x

It's a school assignment, an event management system. It will write the data to a txt file and retrieve it. Its mostly a CRUD program but not sure why it is not running. It shows space as an error on VS CODE IDE.

It will Create a customer, ask for the seats that he want to book. He can also delete the seats as per ref number before 24 hours.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the Event System")


def menu():
    print("Choose the number from menu")
    print("1:Create Customer")
    print("2:Reserve a seat")
    print("3.Cancel the seat")
    print("4.Exit the Event System")
    option = input("put down the number")
return option

def executingmenuinputchoice(option):
    if(option == 1):
        createcust()
    elif(option == 2):
        reserveseat()
    elif(option == 3):
        cancelseat()
    elif(option == 4):
        exit()
    else:
        print('you have chose a wrong option')
        menu()


def createcust():
    print('Provide Customer details')
    name = input('Full name? --> ')
    pno = input('phone number? -> ')
    email = input('Email Id? --> ')
    try:
        file = open("cust.txt", "r")
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
        last_lines = lines[-1]
        content = last_lines.split()
        refno = random.randint(10001, 99999)
        file.close()
        file = open("cust.txt", "a")
        file.write("\n"+" "+name+" "+pno+" "+email+" "+refno)
        file.close()
        print(refno + 'is your reference number')
        print('Added Customer to file')
    except IOError:
        print("File doesn't exist at location")
    except TypeError:
        print('input proper data')
    return createcust()


def customerexist(refno):
    try:
       file = open("cust.txt", "r")
       for line in file:
            content = line.split()
            if (refno == int(content[4])):
                file.close()
                return True,int(content[5])
    except IOError:
            print("File doesn't exist")
            file.close()
    return False,0

def reserveseat():
    referencenumber=input("Enter the Reference Number-->")
    refexist =referenceexist(referencenumber)
    if(refexist==True):
            seatsyouwantbook=input("Number of seats you want to book? ->")
            date=datetime.datetime.now()
            seats=seats+seatsyouwantbook
            newline=""
    try:
        file=open("cust.txt","r")
        lines=file.read().splitlines()
        last_linesno=len(lines)
        currentLine=1
        for line in lines:
            content=line.split
            if(currentline!=last_linesno):
                if(refno==int(content[4])):
                    file.close()
                    return True,int(content[5])
    except IOError:
            print("FIle never existed")
            file.close()
    return False,0

def cancelseat():
    try:
        file=open("cust.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            content=line.split()
            if (refno==int(content[4])):
                file.close()
                return True,int(content[5])
    except IOError:
        print("File doesn't exist")
        file.close()
        return False,0
```

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 41)
```

I want it to run properly so, I can submit it again.

Comment: Please add traceback stack, with the code

Comment: @vasuDeo.S not sure how to do it. Will try now

Comment: just copy the whole error stack (aka error that appeared)

Comment: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 41)

Comment: copy the stack in the question, by editing it

Comment: Your code is just littered with syntax error's, and wrong indentation. If you fix those, there are quite likely chances that your error might be resolved too

Comment: @vasudeo.s tried and removed a few. Not sure of other ones. updated the code

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your whole code, but at least got it running to the point that you could further rectify it:-

```
import random
print("Welcome to the Event System")

def customerexist(refno):
    try:
       file = open("cust.txt", "r")
       for line in file:
            content = line.split()
            if (refno == int(content[4])):
                file.close()
                return True,int(content[5])
    except IOError:
            print("File doesn't exist")
            file.close()
    return False,0

def reserveseat():
    referencenumber=input("Enter the Reference Number-->")
    refexist =referenceexist(referencenumber)
    if(refexist==True):
            seatsyouwantbook=input("Number of seats you want to book? ->")
            date=datetime.datetime.now()
            seats=seats+seatsyouwantbook
            newline=""
    try:
        file=open("cust.txt","r")
        lines=file.read().splitlines()
        last_linesno=len(lines)
        currentLine=1
        for line in lines:
            content=line.split
            if(currentline!=last_linesno):
                if(refno==int(content[4])):
                    file.close()
                    return True,int(content[5])
    except IOError:
            print("FIle never existed")
            file.close()
    return False,0

def cancelseat():
    try:
        file = open("cust.txt","r")
        for line in file:
            content=line.split()
            if (refno==int(content[4])):
                file.close()
                return True,int(content[5])
    except IOError:
        print("File doesn't exist")
        file.close()
        return False,0

def createcust():
    print('Provide Customer details')
    name = input('Full name? --> ')
    pno = input('phone number? -> ')
    email = input('Email Id? --> ')
    try:
        file = open("cust.txt", "r")
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
        last_lines = lines[-1]
        content = last_lines.split()
        refno = random.randint(10001, 99999)
        file.close()
        file = open("cust.txt", "a")
        file.write("\n"+" "+name+" "+pno+" "+email+" "+refno)
        file.close()
        print(refno + 'is your reference number')
        print('Added Customer to file')
    except IOError:
        print("File doesn't exist at location")
    except TypeError:
        print('input proper data')
    return createcust()

def menu():
    print("Choose the number from menu")
    print("1:Create Customer")
    print("2:Reserve a seat")
    print("3.Cancel the seat")
    print("4.Exit the Event System")
    option = input("put down the number")
    return option

def executingmenuinputchoice(option):

    option = int(option)
    if(option == 1):
        createcust()
    elif(option == 2):
        reserveseat()
    elif(option == 3):
        cancelseat()
    elif(option == 4):
        exit()
    else:
        print('you have chose a wrong option')
        menu()


executingmenuinputchoice(menu())
```

**REASON FOR ERRORS:-**

- Your indentation was all over the place, python language
  prioritizes indentation as it uses it to figure out a block span, so you should
  keep a consistent indentation scheme throughout your code.
- Python uses top down approach for ~interpreting the
  program, i.e. It only keeps track of the stuff that it had already
  encountered. In your code, the function `executingmeninputchoice()`
  and `menu()` (the two primary functions used for UI) were stacked
  above all other function, therefore when you tried to call other
  function from these two function, they aren't called. As the program
  doesn't know whether these functions exists or not (as it hasn't
  encountered them yet)
- A logical error existed in function
  `executingmenuinputchoice(option)` as you were trying to take in
  input a string and were comparing it with integer values, and
  therefore every time the operation failed and the control got shifted
  to the `else` block, therefore every time you got the same output
  `'you have chose a wrong option'` regardless of whether the input was
  legal or not

**P.S.:-** I haven't tested your full code, as this isn't a code for me service, other logical errors may also exist, so I would recommend you to find and fix those too.